# gunzip after Automatic ftp crc length error

Tags: linux, unix, ftp, gunzip

I am facing an crc error/length error on .gz file of a file to server.

While manually retrieving the file, I am getting a size 1932 bytes and gunzips fine without any problem.

But when I retrieve it through a shell script, the file arriving is 1931 bytes.

Funny part is I am ftping 3 files and 2 of them are arriving correctly.

This is how I automated it :

```
echo "user $username $password" > $BATCH

echo "get reston.txt.gz reston.txt.gz" >> $BATCH
echo "get tuffnel.txt.gz tuffnel.txt.gz" >> $BATCH
echo "get atlanta.txt.gz atlanta.txt.gz" >> $BATCH

echo "exit" >> $BATCH

ftp -n -v $ipaddress < $BATCH > $LOG
```

then

```
gunzip *.txt.gz
```

tuffnel, atlanta works fine, reston wont gunzip unless downloaded manually.

Thanks in advance,
Lebu

Comment: Maybe FTP defaults to ascii mode? try "BIN" as the first command.

Comment: Try using wget or curl to download a file via FTP. They are better designed for file download.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe FTP defaults to ASCII/text mode? try "BIN" as the first command:

```
echo "user $username $password" > $BATCH
echo "BIN" >> $BATCH

echo "get reston.txt.gz reston.txt.gz" >> $BATCH
echo "get tuffnel.txt.gz tuffnel.txt.gz" >> $BATCH
echo "get atlanta.txt.gz atlanta.txt.gz" >> $BATCH

echo "exit" >> $BATCH

ftp -n -v $ipaddress < $BATCH > $LOG
```

Comment: does changing the order of files sent change the file that has the error? If its the last file in the group that always fails, then maybe you can add a dummy file as the last one? Good luck.